# python finding text and after that text multiple numbers

Tags: python, arrays

I have big xml file and I want edit it with notepad++ (python script).
I need replace all numbers in text like this

```
(x text)="number1;number2;number3;number4;number5;number6"
```

to numbers divided on 2 (no float numbers).

```
(x text)="(number1)/2;(number2)/2;(number3)/2;(number4)/2;(number5)/2;(number6)/2"
```

My code:

```
import re
text = editor.getText()
for m in re.finditer( 'x text', text ):
    numbers = [int(n.group(1)) for n in num.finditer(text)]  //here we should make array of that numbers
    numbers []= numbers []/2 //then divide on 2 (integer)
    map (numbers)   //and return
```

Comment: Python comments start with `#`, not `//`.

Comment: What is the problem you're currently facing?

Comment: how replace that numbers after text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
import re

my_re = re.compile(";".join(r"(\d+)" for i in range(6)))

return re.sub(
  my_re,
  lambda match: ";".join(str(int(match.group(i)) / 2) for i in range(1, 7)),
  editor.getText())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mystr="1;5;7;10;11;20"
mystr=';'.join(map(lambda x:str(int(x)/2),mystr.split(';')))
```

Comment: Look again. I have edited it. mystr=';'.join(map(lambda x:str(int(x)/2),mystr.split(';'))) will return '0;2;3;5;5;10'.